# Jquery plugin simplemodal not displaying properly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, simplemodal

I am using EricMarin's [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).I am not getting the modalpopup to be displayed correctly.I am new to use jquery plugins and could not find where i have gone wrong

Here's  jquery scripts i was using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the css i've used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/simplemodal.css" />
```

This is the simplemodal.css file

```
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
background:url(/Images/x.png) no-repeat; /* adjust url as required */
width:25px;
height:29px;
display:inline;
z-index:3200;
position:absolute;
top:-15px;
right:-18px;
cursor:pointer;
}
[if lt IE 7]>
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
    background:none;
    right:-14px;
    width:22px;
    height:26px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
        src='Images/x.png', sizingMethod='scale'
    );
}
```

Here's the jquery function i have used to display modal popup

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {   

        $("#btnAdd").click(function(){                
            $("#tblSession").modal();
        });
   });
 </script>
```

Here's the table i have used to display modal popup

```
<table id="tblSession" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any reason why not use `jQuery-ui` http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: Remove `...src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js">...`. You try to use 2 different jQuery versions.

Comment: One is jqueryui and other is jquery.Are they same? They are used in  [jquery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).Sorry if i am wrong

Comment: What I meant was why not use jquery-ui exclusively. It has a dialog widget which can be made into a modal dialog like simplemodal.

Comment: You are using two jquery libraries.. One is hosted at Google 1.9.1 and the other one is at jquery.com 1.10.1. You should only have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your code provide, I think you should hide the table by adding `.hide { display: none }` class on it and then all you need to do is run the modal.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/gpest/1/)

In addition, as @da_re said you should not add jQuery twice. Anyhow it is an old version and not available anymore.

Comment: I'm glad that i could help :)